# How do I change the value in ListView when EditText is changed

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

ALL,

I have a ListView where I have a EditText for a quantity, TextView for a price and subtotal for quantity * price. Initially the quantity is set to 1 and everything else is set to price.

Now when the user tries to change the quantity I'd like to calculate the subtotal and set it's value in the appropriate field. However afterTextChange() callback does not use EditText, but rather some Editable object., which means  don't have access to the underlying view and will not be able to update the TextView.

So how do I achieve this? I can't even get the row in the list where I edit the quantity as I don't have access to the underlying EditText object.

Thank you.

P.S.: Obviously this value is discardable, meaning that it will not be stored anywhere after calculation. Only the quantity is important and it will be saved in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

look to notifyDataSetChanged. Use this method in body of onTextChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Some relevant code would be helpful to see exactly how you have it set up but you if your `TextWatcher`, I assume you're using, is an inner class and your `TextView` is a member variable then you do have access to it.

So you could do something like

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        txtView1.setText(s.toString());  // assuming txtView1 is the TextView you want to change
    }
```

If this doesn't help then please post some relevant code so we can see what you have

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code but it will update the `TextView`.